# Use Nextjs built in tools to create routing similar to 'react-router-dom'

Tags: reactjs, next.js, react-router-dom

I am new to **Nextjs** and also react
I am creating a web application similar to Facebook in its ui
which have left menu and main component in the center and some ads or cards on the right side [this is a screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tC1mC.png)

I want to switch between feed, messenger and notifications components in the center with the same functionality of `react-router-dom` in the code below but with **NextJS** built in tools

```
<div>
    <Left_side />
    <Center_side>
        <Switch>
            <Route path="/">
                <Feed />
            </Route>
            <Route path="/messages">
                <Messages />
            </Route>
            <Route path="/notifications">
                <Notifications />
            </Route>
        </Switch>
    </Center_side>
    <Right_side />
</div>
```

Comment: You find an answer to this?